# What does 'Forward AND...' mean here?

Tags: adjectives

Here is the line from an [Indian daily](http://www.hindustantimes.com/specials/football/worldcup2014/fwc-topstories/no-10s-messi-and-benzema-share-limelight-in-brazil/sp-article10-1229913.aspx) [photo caption text],

> Argentina's ***forward and Lionel Messi*** prepares to kick the ball to score his team's second goal during the World Cup match against Bosnia Hercegovina at the Maracana Stadium in Rio de Janeiro. (AFP Photo)

I understand the meaning of the noun *forward*

> [forward](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/FORWARD) - *The person who plays the position of forward in certain games, such as basketball, **soccer,** or hockey.*

But how does the former sentence take *forward **and...***? Shouldn't it be *Argentina's **forward Lionel Messi...*** Not sure whether *forward* can go there as an adjective though.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'd think he was going to write *captain* after *and*: *Argentina's forward and captain Lionel Messi*. Just a guess though.

Comment: It was supposed to be *Argentina's forward and captain Lionel Messi*: [Link #1](http://www.gettyimages.com/detail/news-photo/argentinas-forward-and-captain-lionel-messi-prepares-to-news-photo/450678184) [Link #2](http://www.sportsmole.co.uk/football/2014-world-cup/argentinas-forward-and-captain-lionel-messi-prepares-to-kick-the-ball-to-score-his-teams-second-goal-during-the-group-f-football-match-between-argentina-and-bosnia-hercegovina-at-the-maracana-stadium-in-rio-de-janeiro-during-the-2014-fifa-world-cup-on-j_photo_29316.html)

Comment: @CoolHandLouis Exactly!!!

Comment: Based on the comment be @CoolHand it seems like it "means" the editor didn't proofread very well ;^)

Comment: If one is not a "soccer" fan and does not even know Argentina's (uniform) colors, one could also use one's language facilities to posit some such possible correction as Argentina's forward _end,_ on the analogy of American football having a position called tight end.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis you may put your comment as an answer. I'll be happy to upvote/accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is due to a [typo](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+typo).  It was supposed to be ***"Argentina's forward and captain Lionel Messi"***.  I found the following (non-typo) sources using Google Search ([`"Argentina's forward" "Lionel Messi prepares to kick the ball to score"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Argentina%27s+forward%22+%22Lionel+Messi+prepares+to+kick+the+ball+to+score%22)):

- [www.sportsmole.co.uk](http://www.sportsmole.co.uk/football/2014-world-cup/argentinas-forward-and-captain-lionel-messi-prepares-to-kick-the-ball-to-score-his-teams-second-goal-during-the-group-f-football-match-between-argentina-and-bosnia-hercegovina-at-the-maracana-stadium-in-rio-de-janeiro-during-the-2014-fifa-world-cup-on-j_photo_29316.html): "**Argentina's forward and captain Lionel Messi** prepares to kick the ball ... during the 2014 FIFA World Cup..."
- [www.gettyimages.com](http://www.gettyimages.com/detail/news-photo/argentinas-forward-and-captain-lionel-messi-prepares-to-news-photo/450678184): "Caption:**Argentina's forward and captain Lionel Messi** prepares to kick the ball ... during the 2014 FIFA World Cup on June 15, 2014."

Note that standard, formal English would typically require commas, as follows:

> Argentina's forward and captain, Lionel Messi, prepares to kick the ball.

However, news magazines will often eliminate grammatical and syntactical elements when it doesn't reduce clarity. In this case,

> Argentina's forward and captain Lionel Messi prepares to kick the ball.

Now the above sentence, taken out of context, can seem a bit odd since it initially seems to suggest two different people.  But most people who would be reading this within it's natural context would be regular readers of sports and would understand the form.

It may be interesting that this is part of a general pattern in which some rules can be relaxed for shorter phrases (or perhaps conversely, some rules are *required* for longer phrases).  The following sentence would practically demand commas:

> Argentina's forward and newly appointed captain of the team, Lionel Messi, prepares to kick the ball.

---

<sup>Credit to @Fantasier who actually *predicted* the answer before I (independently) researched it.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, the *and* is improper here, and you have the right definition of *forward*. Looking at the picture:

- There's only one Argentinian player
- That player is Lionel Messi
- He plays the position of forward
- He is the only one preparing to kick the ball

Clearly, both *Lionel Messi* and *forward* refer to the same person here.

*Argentina's forward Lionel Messi* is a valid grammatical construct. *Forward* is a noun and the subject of the sentence. *Lionel Messi* is a noun phrase functioning adjectivally to describe *forward*; it tells us *which specific Argentinian forward*, as they have more than one. It's added as a parenthetical remark or aside, and you can insert some commas into the sentence to make the meaning more obvious:

> Argentina's forward, Lionel Messi, prepares to kick the ball to score his team's second goal during the World Cup match against Bosnia Hercegovina at the Maracana Stadium in Rio de Janeiro. (AFP Photo)

If you wanted to name both the player and position in a compound subject, you could use *forward Messi*, though this construction is quite rare in American English. I assume you mean using *forward* as a title, similar to *Doctor Connors* or *Mister Smith*. *The forward Messi* or *Tendulkar the striker* are much more common phrasings and function grammatically the same as *Argentina's forward Lionel Messi* from the sentence in question. Names of sports positions aren't generally given the same level of credence as employment or honorific titles.

Answer (score 0):

I think the editor of the hindustantimes is the one that missed something. It looks like this sentence was intended to be written differently, and ended up mangled.

The editor saw "x"and "y", saw two people on the picture, and moved on, I guess.

Comment: That seems a valid *thought*.

Comment: Let _me_ edit captions under cricket pictures, and you will get similar nonsense :)

Comment: There, the matter could be clear (as a blunder though!) but here, the confusion occurred as *forward* is a noun and I thought is it someone else (forward) **and** Messi preparing for a 'kick'? Also, can *forward* go as an adjective? - *Forward Messi?*

Comment: The thing is that the only Argentinian player on in the picture is Lionel Messi, who happens to be Argentina's forward. It is impossible that they mean two different people with that. An editor with a serious interest in soccer would have noticed that. And no, "Argentina's forward" in this context _only_ means Lionel Messi, their forward player.

Comment: Again, is *Forward Messi* possible? Something like *Striker Tendulkar?* (The person who's batting facing the ball currently).

Comment: Yes, the "and"should be removed, and I would put comma's around _Lionel Messi_ - but those comma's are optional :).